# Turn off sudo requirements for all Python commands

Tags: python, macos, shell, terminal, sudo

How do I (on Mac OSX) remove the need for sudo when working with Python. It can stay on for everything else - but I would prefer to always be in admin mode so I don't always have to type in sudo.

Comment: What *do* you use `sudo` for? `easy_install`? Then you should rather be looking into [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/virtualenv.html).

Comment: You could enable the root account, but I recommend against that. The best way would be learn some shell shortcuts that reduce the need for typing `sudo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a programming question, but I'll give it a whirl anyway.

The safest way to do this is probably to begin your terminal session with `sudo -s` which gives you a root shell. Then anything you do in that shell (including but not limited to running `python` or Python scripts) will be as root, with full access to everything on the machine.

As a sledgehammer approach, you can `setuid` the Python executable and make it always run as root. This is, however, a terrible, terrible idea; *any* Python script will then have root privileges! If someone can get some gnarly Python onto your box and convince you to run it, they then have complete access to your machine.

Still, if you want to live on the edge, you can try:

```
sudo chown root `which python`
sudo chmod u+s `which python`
```

One way to mitigate this (ever-so-slightly) would be to make a copy of the python interpreter (name it, say, `python-root`), perform the above on that copy, and invoke this for your interactive sessions. Scripts would still use the stock `python` executable and not run as root. Of course, this is no fewer keystrokes than `sudo python` although at least you wouldn't need to enter a password. It would also be convenient for a `#!` (shebang) line in scripts that always need to run as root.

Comment: Hmm, +1 for a solution, -1 for opening Pandora's box, +1 for noting it's extra terribleness.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean not to type your password for each command you can run python with sudo as you would for do any other program, in the shell you type `sudo python`. But if you mean to have python running always with root privileges, I can be of no help to you, sorry.

Comment: I meant the latter - yes.